# Apply Function Recursively On an Array of Inputs

Tags: python, recursion

Suppose I have a complicated function function `f(A, B)` . I want to recursively apply this to a list of inputs, `X = [C, D, E]`.

I would like to know how I can define a function `g` so that the output of `g([C, D, E])` is `f(f(C, D), E)`, for arbitrary lengths of `X`.

Let us define an example function:

```
def f(A, B):
    return A + B
```

How would I define `g`?

Comment: There is `reduce`.

Answer (score 1):

There is [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) that does that:

```
from functools import reduce
result = reduce(f, [1, 2, 3])
```

If you prefer to define it yourself:

```
def g(lst):
    res = lst[0]
    for val in lst[1:]:
        res = f(res, val)
    return res

result = g([1, 2, 3])
```

If you want to get just one argument using `reduce`, then embed it as follows:

```
g = lambda lst: reduce(f, lst)
```

Comment: I had no idea this was a function! May I add an additional single-line lambda solution for g to your answer?

Comment: Go ahead! All to the benefit of the community ;-)